# express-session not responding to request with "Cookie-Set" header

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, session-cookies, express-session

I have an nginx server, forwarding requests to a nodejs/express backend. The server has an ssl cert and I am connecting over https. I'm using the [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) module and the cookie configuration object looks like so,

```
{ secure: true, sameSite: true, httpOnly: true, domain: "example.com" }
```

I am also setting a proxy for the express server like so,

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
```

The X-Forward headers for nginx look like so,

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forward-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto $scheme;
```

Any suggestions? I've tried connecting over ngrok locally before I set the domain and that seemed to work, but that configuration still did not work for nginx.

Comment: Can you share the NGINX error.log? What do you mean by "not responding"? Do you mean NGINX can not connect to the backend-server?

Comment: @TimoStark I don't see errors in the error.log. By not responding, I mean the "Set-Cookie" header is missing from the Express server's response to the browser's request.

Comment: can you share your full NGINX configiuration? That would help to better understand the problem. thanks